# write '3d' vector pod type to binary file c++

Tags: c++, vector, binary

I made the following sample code (compile with -std=c++11)

It's a 3d vector 10*20*30 filled with the number 8 everywhere.
I can't figure out how to write it to disk and read it back. Can someone tell me how please or complete the r-rw routines?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //'3d' vector filled with 8's
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>  all8s (10,std::vector<std::vector<int>>(20,std::vector <int>(30,8)));;
    //print the whole
    std::cout << "1st size " << all8s.size() << " \n";
    for ( auto& elemTop : all8s ) {
        std::cout << "2nd size " << elemTop.size() << " \n";
        for ( auto& elemMiddle : elemTop ) {
            std::cout << "3th size " << elemMiddle.size() << "  \n";
            for ( auto& elemBottom : elemMiddle ){
                std::cout << elemBottom << ",";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    //write binary file
    std::ofstream out("all8s.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    //how do I write this to disk
    out.close();

    //read it?
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>  all8sReloaded;
    std::ifstream in("all8s.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    //how to read it back?
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: You do it by writing/reading each vector of each vector of *the* vector, one at a time. Or, you belay all of that, use just a `std::vector<int>` from the get-go and do the subscript math yourself for wherever it is used.

Comment: Common convention is that you should use `auto const &` if you aren't modifying the elements.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write all the block in a single write sentence. A very simple solution according to your code is:

```
for ( auto& elemTop : all8s )
        for ( auto& elemMiddle : elemTop )
            for ( auto& elemBottom : elemMiddle )
                cout.write (reinterpret_cast(const char*)&elemBottom, sizeof(int));
```

On the other hand, if you want to read them, you would need to know the dimensions of your vectors; it is similar. If not, you would have to save this sizes before the data.

Answer (score 1):

Two nested loops is one possible way, and then write e.g. `&all8s[i][j][0]` (which is the same as `all8s[i][j].data()`). Note that I use vector indexing as example, you could use iterators or the range-based `for` loop like you're already is using.

Reading is easy if you already know the sizes. You can either have the sizes be compile-time fixed sizes like you have for your example `all8s`, or you can save the sizes (dimensions) in the file as a header before the data. No matter how you get the sizes, you then need to [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the vectors, and read it basically the same way you write it.

---

Or simply use a [serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) which have most of the functionality already built-in.